# Computation in Oracle Apex not returning expected result

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am getting confused about computation points, such as before_header and after_header etc.

I have a computation, which needs to take a page item value, and then return as result.

The computation is a PL/SQL Function Body as below:

```
DECLARE
   v_response varchar2(1500);
BEGIN
  IF :P4_RENEWAL_REQUIRED = 'Yes' THEN
        v_response := 'According to Register, a license renewal WILL BE required to maintain this registration. Please choose whether you agree or disagree with this statement.';
 ELSE
       v_response:='Forget about it...';
 END IF;
  return v_response;
END;
```

The page item :P4_RENEWAL_REQUIRED is a calculated field which is a SQL value, which relies on a database populated page item P4_RENEWAL_NOT_REQUIRED.  It simply turns a Yes to a No and a No to Yes.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN V('P4_RENEWAL_NOT_REQUIRED')='Yes' Then 'No' ELSE 
CASE WHEN  V('P4_RENEWAL_NOT_REQUIRED')='No' Then 'Yes' ELSE '??' END END) FROM DUAL
```

My computation will not return the result.  The P4_RENEWAL_REQUIRED value will be clearly 'Yes' but the computation will return 'Forget about it'.  If I go into page edit view, and then run the page again - the value shows the correct value of

'According to Register, a license renewal WILL BE required to maintain this registration. Please choose whether you agree or disagree with this statement.'

This implies to me that the computation is operating on an old session value of P4_RENEWAL_REQUIRED.

I am not really sure what the computation points have to do with this, but if I have data being returned via a Fetch Row process executing on After Header, which then is populating the fields in the regions such as P4_RENEWAL_NOT_REQUIRED, and then P4_RENEWAL_REQUIRED is being calculated....how do I get a computation to populate a field in another region which has a dependency on the existing page items?

I have tried making my computation execute before footer, before regions, after footer etc. but nothing works.

I am not sure how all the Before Footer works, or how the page items get populated in which point, when all of this is rendered server side.

For example if I set my computation to calculate "After Region" is it too late to then use that value IN a region as the regions have already been rendered?

If I need to calculate a value in my computation to use it in a region and use "Before Region" computation point, have the page items I need to use been tied to the page items by the underlying query at that point or am I too early.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Not totally clear to me: what is the source for P4_RENEWAL_NOT_REQUIRED? Set to "always" or "only when session state is empty"?

Comment: It is set to Always

Comment: Sorry, may not've been clearly stated: the source type for this item, to what is it set? SQL Query?

Comment: P4_RENEWAL_NOT_REQUIRED is a database column, I convert it by reversing it (Yes->No, No->Yes) in the field P4_RENEWAL_REQUIRED, which is a SQL statement, which I notice is not set to "Always"

 SELECT (CASE WHEN V('P4_RENEWAL_NOT_REQUIRED')='Yes' Then 'No' ELSE 
CASE WHEN  V('P4_RENEWAL_NOT_REQUIRED')='No' Then 'Yes' ELSE '??' END END) FROM DUAL

Comment: Well -for starters: it should really at least be set to "Always": you want the value to be "retrieved" each time the page is rendered - other problems notwithstanding

Comment: OK, thanks.  Is there any documentation which really explains the page rendering pipeline, i.e. what does AFTER HEADER mean in terms of a computation etc.  I am confused about if I try to render the output of a computation into a region on a page item, if my computation happens after the rendering of the regions for example...and when the page items get bound to the database columns and expressions, for example do page items only get bound to the fields as the page items are rendered?  I find Apex really useful, but the documentation is very high level.

Comment: (Did the "always" fix it btw?) I'll try to write down some additional info on the process points and session state in an answer

Comment: Hi, sorry - yes it did fix it, if you add it as an answer I will accept it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Source Used" should be set to "Always" since you want the value to reflect it's dependant value. When set to "Only when session state is null" the value will only be fetched when the session state is empty. After a first submit (or any other method of setting a value in session state, such as a computation) the source will no longer be retrieved each time. This'll give you the impression the value is old.

As for docs: it's usually really transparent, but where usually some confusion exists is when values are retrieved through the fetch row process: this process fetches the values for the relevant items (source=database column) and keeps them in memory for the duration of the render (an "in-memory session state"). These values will always be used for the item's source, though the values are NOT kept in session state afterwards (=when render finishes). You can verify this by checking session state after a page has rendered: all empty! I know I've read this somewhere, but it's not detailed in the docs themselves on how "fetch row" works.

Computations will set the value of the items in session state, persistently. Yes - you can use them to set the value of an item and it has this additional effect. This "caused" the problem here (in combination): simply deriving the value in the item source would work fine, as long as session state is not kept through a submit. Since a computation was used, the source was always disregarded since "only when session state is null" was used.

Performing a computation on a database column does set the session state though, but the in-memory session state and source type have overruled that value. After render the session state set through the computation still persists. When submitting the submitted values will once again be put in session state. So, that's a weird situation. This can be really weird though - try to avoid this as it'll be though to logic through this mess.

This does give meaning to the different computation points. You could compute an item after the rendering has ended, and the session state will be set. The item will have rendered with a value prior to the computation (if done after the render, otherwise, it depends on eg source) and then have the value persisted in session state.
I can't come up with an example as I've never had to use that situation though. Personally, the before and after region points don't mean much to me.
The before headers and after headers will usually be the most used points, and as with all processing, will be sequential. Use where appropriate.

Once again, in normal situations where the items are all derived through their source settings: they'll behave normal and no persistance to session state will occur. Processes (except "Fetch"!) and computations will make values persist in session state.